# Is it possible to add custom category in siri shortcut intentdefinition file?

Tags: ios, ios12

I want to add intent for siri shotcut in my app.  The category in intent definition file which suits my requirement is “add”. But every category has some predefined reply from siri like “ok/done/added”, apart from the reply which my app says. Is there anyway to customise category or reply? And I don’t want “App Name says” in reply. Can I remove that?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you, as I want to create a custom category. But after some research, I came to the conclusion that it is not possible, yet.

I ended up with using one of the categories provided, which suits my application the best.